# How to create and save distinct scatterplots using matplotlib and nested 'for-loops' for labelled data?

Tags: python, matplotlib, nested-loops, scatter-plot

I have a dataset containing 10 features and corresponding labels. I am using scatterplot to plot distinct pair of features to see which of them describe the labels perfectly (which means that total 45 plots will be created). In order to do that, I used a nested loop format. The code shows no error and I obtained all the plots as well. However, there is clearly something wrong with the code because each new scatterplot that gets created and saved is accumulating points from the previous ones as well. I am attaching the complete code which I used. How to fix this problem? Below is the link for raw dataset:

https://github.com/IITGuwahati-AI/Learning-Content/raw/master/Phase%203%20-%202020%20(Summer)/Week%201%20(Mar%2028%20-%20Apr%204)/assignment/data.txt

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

data_url ='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/diwakar1412/Learning-Content/master/DiwakarDas_184104503/datacsv.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(data_url)

df.head()

def transform_label(value):
    if value >= 2:
        return "BLUE"
    else:
        return "RED"

df["Label"] = df.Label.apply(transform_label)

df.head()


colors = {'RED':'r', 'BLUE':'b'}

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for i in range(1,len(df.columns)):
    for j in range(i+1,len(df.columns)):
        for k in range(len(df[str(i)])):
            ax.scatter(df[str(i)][k], df[str(j)][k], color=colors[df['Label'][k]])
        ax.set_title('F%svsF%s' %(i,j))
        ax.set_xlabel('%s' %i)
        ax.set_ylabel('%s' %j)
        plt.savefig('F%svsF%s' %(i,j))
```

[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7uyMq.png)

Comment: This is the entire code. The url is where the raw data is stored. You can run this as it is.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a new figure each time. Try to put

`fig, ax = plt.subplots()`

inside your loop:

```
for i in range(1,len(df.columns)):
    for j in range(i+1,len(df.columns)):
        fig, ax = plt.subplots() # <-------------- here
        for k in range(len(df[str(i)])):
            ax.scatter(df[str(i)][k], df[str(j)][k], color=colors[df['Label'][k]])
        ax.set_title('F%svsF%s' %(i,j))
        ax.set_xlabel('%s' %i)
        ax.set_ylabel('%s' %j)
        plt.savefig('/Users/Alessandro/Desktop/tmp/F%svsF%s' %(i,j))
```

Comment: remember to select my answer as the correct one (the green check), thank you